# C# public static method - shares info between users

Tags: c#, static

I have a asp.net website and a class library as a project reference. In the class library I have public class a couple of static methods. When user logs into their account, I make a call to one of the static method to load the info related to the user. I had some instance where when I login as user A, I am able to see info related to user B. Is this because of static methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's because of static *variables*. Those are shared by the whole `AppDomain` - which pretty much means "the whole website on that machine" in this case.

It's hard to know exactly what you should be doing without any more information, but I strongly suspect you're just storing user information in static variables, which is *never* going to be the right way to go.

Quite how you manage user sessions is up to you, and reams of text have been written on this no doubt - but using static variables will cause exactly the issue you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

That could be, I would have to see your code to be sure, is the info also stored as statics? then it is correct as statics are shared between instances